# Specify Keytab Location for Slapd

Tags: openldap, kerberos, slapd

I need help. How can I set up the ldap keytab location path in order that slapd uses it instead of the system /etc/krb5.keytab?

I can't find the configuration in documentation.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done in the init configuration as an environmental variable.
For instance in CentOS7:

```
$ grep KRB5_KTNAME /etc/sysconfig/slapd
KRB5_KTNAME="FILE:/etc/openldap/ldap.keytab"
```

In a debian derived systems it's likely that this will instead be in `/etc/defaults/` rather than `/etc/sysconfig/`.